# Meaning of 'we are following up on the correspondence below'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Two days after being asked to fill out a document and get it signed, I receive an email just saying:

> "We are following up on the correspondence below".

I'm not a native speaker, so I'd like to ask if this is a kind reminder or if it has some other meaning. The conversation occurred with a law firm.

Comment: Is there a reference at the end of the letter ("below"), confirming the subject?

Comment: @TimLymington Yes, the email sent (two days) before is at the end of it!

Comment: If you're really saying that was the only content of the message, they made a very big mistake. Ask them what they left out.

Otherwise, what did they actually write, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-reading the OP’s question, I believe we have interpreted it incorrectly.
The OP states,

> Two days after being asked to fill out a document and get it signed, I receive an email just saying...

I now interpret this to mean that the ***OP*** was asked to fill out a document.  Presumably the letter’s author has not received the filled-out document yet and is *following up* to see if it has been done yet.

This use of follow up is, as OP suspects, a “kind reminder” to fill out the document and return it to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes called a *holding email* (or *holding letter*), simply to reassure you that though the lawyers are not able to give you a proper reply yet (probably your matter is at the end of a to-do list), your case has not been forgotten.

Comment: The first time, I've ever encountered this phrase... thanks a lot for the clarification! (Can't vote yet...)

Comment: @Jan... Your dictionary may have "follow up"

Comment: I now think this is probably the wrong interpretation. See my answer.